# Variable unintendedly being set

Tags: python, list, variables, set

I am trying to move stuff round a screen. The pygame is just for easy text input. This is a very short bit of my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
sensitivity = 5 # How fast it moves
rot=rot_speed = [0, 0]
done=pause = False
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 450))
screen.fill((255,255,255))
pygame.display.flip()
while not done: # ---------- Main program loop ---------- #
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # If they pressed a key
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # Did they click quit?
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: # Has a key been pressed?
            type_key = 1
            print("SENSITIVITY", sensitivity, rot_speed,".", rot)
            if event.key == pygame.K_w: # Up key pressed
                rot_speed[1] = sensitivity*-1
            if event.key == pygame.K_s: # Down key pressed
                rot_speed[1] = sensitivity
            if event.key == pygame.K_a: # Left key pressed
                rot_speed[0] = sensitivity*-1
            if event.key == pygame.K_d: # Right key pressed
                rot_speed[0] = sensitivity
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if pause == False:
                    pause = True
                else:
                    pause = False
            print("KEYS", sensitivity, rot_speed,".", rot)
    if pause == False:
        print("rot_speed", rot_speed)
```

The problem I am having is that the variables `rot` and `rot_speed` are being set when I only try set `rot_speed`. Any ideas? When I didn't have the speed as lists and as individual variables it worked but I may have changed the code in some other ways. Put print statements around the setting of variables, it's very strange.

Comment: @VasilisG. Forgot to say - each list needs 2 items as one is x and one is y

Comment: `rot=rot_speed = [0, 0]` assigns the same list to both variables. You are assigning to `rot` there.

Comment: If you did not want to assign to `rot`, then just *remove `rot=` from that line*.

Comment: If you wanted the two variables to be two *separate* list objects, then assign two separate list objects. You are now sharing a single object between them, you did not get two copies.

Comment: @MartijnPieters They are to preset the list values. This is important to the bigger code. The problem is when you press the arrow keys...

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh i get it! Im assigning values to the same variable as they both direct to one value! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing `rot, rot_speed = [0, 0], [0, 0]`. This will set `rot` and `rot_speed` to separate values. Currently you have `rot = rot_speed = [0, 0]` which means that you're setting `rot` to be a pointer to `rot_speed`. Because of this, it will only change whenever `rot_speed` changes.

Comment: Great thanks! I will accept answer when it will let me!

Comment: You're welcome! Things like this are frustrating for all of us when we first start programming.

Comment: yeah i learnt that as well but i forgot it was too far back in my mind :)

Answer (score 2):

You assigned *one* list object to both names:

```
rot=rot_speed = [0, 0]
```

This does not assign two copies; you simply have two different labels both referencing the same thing. Any mutations to `rot_speed` will be visible via `rot` too:

```
>>> rot = rot_speed = [0, 0]
>>> rot is rot_speed   # they are the same object
True
>>> rot[0] = 42  # mutating the list
>>> rot_speed    # changes visible in both places
[42, 0]
```

Create two separate lists:

```
rot = [0, 0]
rot_speed = [0, 0]
```

You may want to read up on how Python variables (names) work. I highly recommend Ned Batchelder's [*Facts and myths about Python names and values*](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).